# Unique index has 0 in index size w 1.5M rows

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, size

Ive been looking for a good explanation but i havent found anything to my satisfaction.

I have this table

Table email

```
CREATE TABLE `emails` (
  `UrlId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `EmailAddress` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `UrlId_UNIQUE` (`UrlId`,`EmailAddress`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_UrlId_EmailAdress` FOREIGN KEY (`UrlId`) REFERENCES `urls` (`UrlId`) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

When i run this query

```
SELECT count(*) '# of tables',
concat(round(sum(table_rows)/1000000,2),'M') '# of rows',
concat(round(sum(data_length)/(1024*1024*1024),2),'G') 'Size of data',
concat(round(sum(index_length)/(1024*1024*1024),2),'G') 'Size of index',
concat(round(sum(data_length+index_length)/(1024*1024*1024),2),'G') 'Total size',
round(sum(index_length)/sum(data_length),2) 'Index fraction'
FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_name='emails';
```

I get this result

```
# of tables, # of rows, Size of data, Size of index, Total size, Index fraction
1            1.52M      0.17G         0.00G          0.17G       0.00
```

The table has over 1.5 millions rows, but the index size is 0.

Then i have this table

```
CREATE TABLE `search_tags` (
  `TagId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `UrlId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `Unique_UrlId_SearchTagId` (`UrlId`,`TagId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Unique_SearchTagId_UrlId` (`TagId`,`UrlId`),
  CONSTRAINT `SearchTagId` FOREIGN KEY (`TagId`) REFERENCES `search_tag` (`SearchTagId`) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `UrlId` FOREIGN KEY (`UrlId`) REFERENCES `urls` (`UrlId`) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

When i run the checkup query on that table i get this

```
# of tables, # of rows, Size of data, Size of index, Total size, Index fraction
1            77.06M     3.01G         1.36G          4.37G       0.45
```

As you can see i have 2 unique indexes on the search_tags table. This one does infact show a index size.

Why is the size of the index in `emails` 0? Is the the actual data also the index since it is unique? Why does the `search_tags` have index size? Is it beacuse i have double indexes and one index is created on the side of the unique data? Or am I way way off?

EDIT

I decided to create a test table of `search_tags` with only 1 unique index. And the result are as expected.

```
# table_name       # of rows  Size of data  Size of index  Total size  Index fraction
search_tags        74.96M     3.01G         1.36G          4.37G       0.45
search_tags_test   67.92M     1.81G         0.00G          1.81G       0.00
```

I guess its safe to say that unique indexes that cover the entire tables columns, the whole data becomes the index, hence, the index size is 0.

I have however in the past said, "its safe to say"...and being 100% sure of my assumtion and later find out that im not correct. I just want to get this confirmed by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a part of the description of [the InnoDB engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-storage-engine.html):

> InnoDB tables arrange your data on disk to optimize common queries
>   based on primary keys. Each InnoDB table has a primary key index
>   called the clustered index that organizes the data to minimize I/O for
>   primary key lookups.